# May anyone explain to me why the texture doesn't show? [PyOpenGL]

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, 3d, pyopengl

The relevant methods to see are: **init**, genTexture, onDisplayEvent and table_leg_model.

The 'wood1.png' is a 64x64 image.

Code :

```
import Image

from math import cos
from math import pi
from math import sin
from numpy import array
from numpy import uint8
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from sys import argv

# Classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------
class AppGL(object):
    def __init__(self, title, position=(100, 100), size=(400, 400)):
        # Properties -----------------------------------------------------------
        self.angle_delta = 4.0
        self.position = position
        self.rotateX = [0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        self.rotateY = [0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
        self.size = size
        self.translate = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

        self.textures_index = {
            'wood1': 0,
        }
        self.textures = array([0] * len(self.textures_index), uint8)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        # General initialization
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        glGenTextures(len(self.textures), self.textures)
        self.genTexture('wood1', 'textures/wood1.png')
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        # GLUT initialization --------------------------------------------------
        glutInit(argv)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
        glutInitWindowPosition(*self.position)
        glutInitWindowSize(*self.size)
        glutCreateWindow(title)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        # Callbacks ------------------------------------------------------------
        glutDisplayFunc(self.onDisplayEvent)
        glutKeyboardFunc(self.onKeyEvent)
        glutMotionFunc(self.onMouseMotionEvent)
        glutMouseFunc(self.onMouseButtonEvent)
        glutReshapeFunc(self.onReshapeEvent)
        glutSpecialFunc(self.onSpecialKeyEvent)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        # Arrays ---------------------------------------------------------------
        data = []
        #data.extend(table_model(0.4, 40))
        data.extend(table_leg_model())
        #data.extend(table_model(0.2, 40))

        glInterleavedArrays(GL_T2F_V3F, 0, array(data, "f"))
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def genTexture(self, index, path):
        img = Image.open(path)
        texture_data = array(list(img.getdata()), uint8)

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.textures[self.textures_index[index]])
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data)

    def onDisplayEvent(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glLoadIdentity()
        gluLookAt(0, 0, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0)

        glTranslatef(*self.translate)
        glRotatef(*self.rotateX)
        glRotatef(*self.rotateY)

        # Visual scene ---------------------------------------------------------
        glPushMatrix()

        # Table -----------------------~
        #glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, 39, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, array(xrange(0, 80, 2), "d"))
        #glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, 39, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, array(xrange(1, 80, 2), "d"))
        #glDrawElements(GL_QUAD_STRIP, 80, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, array(xrange(0, 80), "d"))

        getMatrixHead()
        glTranslatef(-0.1, -0.1, 0)
        #glDrawElements(GL_QUAD_STRIP, 10, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, array(xrange(80, 90), "d"))
        glDrawElements(GL_QUAD_STRIP, 10, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, array(xrange(0, 10), "d"))

        #getMatrixHead()
        #glTranslatef(0, 0, 1)
        #glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, 39, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, array(xrange(90, 170, 2), "d"))
        #glDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, 39, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, array(xrange(91, 170, 2), "d"))
        #glDrawElements(GL_QUAD_STRIP, 80, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, array(xrange(90, 170), "d"))

        glPopMatrix()
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        glutSwapBuffers()

    def onKeyEvent(self, key, x, y):
        change = True

        if key == 'a':
            self.translate[0] += 1

        elif key == 'd':
            self.translate[0] -= 1

        elif key == 's':
            self.translate[1] += 1

        elif key == 'w':
            self.translate[1] -= 1

        elif key == 'q':
            self.translate[2] += 1

        elif key == 'e':
            self.translate[2] -= 1

        else:
            change = False

        if change: glutPostRedisplay()

    def onMouseMotionEvent(self, x, y):
        pass

    def onMouseButtonEvent(self, button, state, x, y):
        pass

    def onReshapeEvent(self, width, height):
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(60.0, width / height, 1.0, 100.0)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

    def onSpecialKeyEvent(self, key, x, y):
        change = True

        if key == GLUT_KEY_UP:
            self.rotateX[0] += self.angle_delta

        elif key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            self.rotateX[0] -= self.angle_delta

        elif key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            self.rotateY[0] += self.angle_delta

        elif key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            self.rotateY[0] -= self.angle_delta

        else:
            change = False

        if change: glutPostRedisplay()

    def run(self):
        glutMainLoop()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Functions --------------------------------------------------------------------
def getMatrixHead():
    glPopMatrix()
    glPushMatrix()

def table_model(radius, number_of_points):
    delta = 2 * pi / (number_of_points - 1)
    points = []

    for i in xrange(number_of_points):
        points.extend((radius * cos(i * delta), radius * sin(i * delta), 0.05))
        points.extend((radius * cos(i * delta), radius * sin(i * delta), 0))

    return points

def table_leg_model():
    return (
        0, 0,   0, 0.2, 0,
        0, 1,   0, 0.2, 1.0,
        1, 0,   0, 0, 0,
        1, 1,   0, 0, 1.0,
        #0, 0,   0.2, 0, 0,
        #0, 1,   0.2, 0, 1.0,
        #1, 0,   0.2, 0.2, 0,
        #1, 1,   0.2, 0.2, 1.0,
        #0, 0,   0, 0.2, 0,
        #0, 1,   0, 0.2, 1.0,
    )
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Main -------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AppGL("Moe's Tavern", (300, 100), (800, 600)).run()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The source code can also be found here ~> https://github.com/EPadronU/TavernGL/blob/master/appgl.py

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of just posting a link.  Copying the code here 1) makes it more likely people will actually look at your code and 2) make sure the question is useful to others when the link rots (or you update you code to fix the problem)

Comment: @tcaswell: While I agree that pasting the source code here increases the likelyhood that people read it, having it also available via a public repository increases the likelyhood people will actually try the code and tinker with in on their own machines.

Comment: @datenwolf I agree both is best, but I would err on the side of having the code here as the priority so that the question (and it's hopefully existing answers) are more likely to be useful in 2 years when that file has been changed or the repo no longer exist.

Comment: I am also used to dealing with matplotlib questions which can typically be reduced to < 50 lines for a SSCE.

Comment: @tcaswell: I fully agree, most OpenGL problems can be reduces to < 50 LoC SSCE as well. Well in this case, making a git clone was done quickly and I rewrote the code. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just run down the list of what stroke me curious:

The function `getMatrixHead` makes no sense, at least the naming. At best it will just drop what's been on the stack and make a copy of what's below.

Then you make the typical newbie error of trying to "initialize" OpenGL. Don't do that. Except for loading textures or VBO data make OpenGL calls only from the display function and *nowhere* else. If you made a backtrace whenever a OpenGL function is called it should only happen because ultimately because display was called. If you had done it that way you'd not have made OpenGL called before there was an actual OpenGL context: Only *after* a OpenGL context has been created OpenGL calls have an effect. If using GLUT that's *after* calling `glutCreateWindow`

Now look at that code:

```
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

    glGenTextures(len(self.textures), self.textures)
    self.genTexture('wood1', 'textures/wood1.png')
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    # GLUT initialization --------------------------------------------------
    glutInit(argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowPosition(*self.position)
    glutInitWindowSize(*self.size)
    glutCreateWindow(title)
```

You're making OpenGL calls before there is a context. If you had written it in the following way it would have worked (I also took the liberty at giving it a nice informative loading screen)

```
import Image

from math import cos
from math import pi
from math import sin
from numpy import array
from numpy import uint8
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from sys import argv

# Classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------
class AppGL(object):
    def __init__(self, title, position=(100, 100), size=(400, 400)):
        # Properties -----------------------------------------------------------
        self.angle_delta = 4.0
        self.position = position
        self.rotateX = [0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        self.rotateY = [0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
        self.size = size
        self.translate = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        self.textures = dict()

        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        # GLUT initialization --------------------------------------------------
        glutInit(argv)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
        glutInitWindowPosition(*self.position)
        glutInitWindowSize(*self.size)
        glutCreateWindow(title)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        # Callbacks ------------------------------------------------------------
        glutDisplayFunc(self.onDisplayEvent)
        glutKeyboardFunc(self.onKeyEvent)
        glutMotionFunc(self.onMouseMotionEvent)
        glutMouseFunc(self.onMouseButtonEvent)
        glutReshapeFunc(self.onReshapeEvent)
        glutSpecialFunc(self.onSpecialKeyEvent)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        # Arrays ---------------------------------------------------------------
        self.tablelegmodel = array( list(table_leg_model()), "f")

        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def loadTexture(self, path):
        if path in self.textures.keys():
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.textures[path])
            return

        glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT)
        glClearColor(0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 1.)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()

        glRasterPos3f(-0.9, 0.9, 0)
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
        glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, "Loading Texture " + path)
        glFinish()
        glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK)

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glPopMatrix()
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glPopMatrix()

        img = Image.open(path)
        texture_data = array(list(img.getdata()), uint8)

        texID = array([0], uint8)
        glGenTextures(1, texID)
        texID = texID[0]

        self.textures[path] = texID
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img.size[0], img.size[1], 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data)

    def onDisplayEvent(self):
        width, height = self.size
        aspect = float(width) / float(height)

        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(60.0, aspect, 1.0, 100.0)

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluLookAt(0, 0, 4, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0)

        glTranslatef(*self.translate)
        glRotatef(*self.rotateX)
        glRotatef(*self.rotateY)

        # Visual scene ---------------------------------------------------------
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslatef(-0.1, -0.1, 0)

        self.loadTexture('textures/wood1.png')

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

        glInterleavedArrays(GL_T2F_V3F, 0, self.tablelegmodel)
        glDrawElements(GL_QUAD_STRIP, 10, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, array(xrange(0, 10), "d"))

        glPopMatrix()
        #-----------------------------------------------------------------------

        glutSwapBuffers()

    def onKeyEvent(self, key, x, y):
        if key == 'a':
            self.translate[0] += 1

        elif key == 'd':
            self.translate[0] -= 1

        elif key == 's':
            self.translate[1] += 1

        elif key == 'w':
            self.translate[1] -= 1

        elif key == 'q':
            self.translate[2] += 1

        elif key == 'e':
            self.translate[2] -= 1

        else:
            return

        glutPostRedisplay()

    def onMouseMotionEvent(self, x, y):
        pass

    def onMouseButtonEvent(self, button, state, x, y):
        pass

    def onReshapeEvent(self, width, height):
        self.size = width, height
        glutPostRedisplay()

    def onSpecialKeyEvent(self, key, x, y):
        if key == GLUT_KEY_UP:
            self.rotateX[0] += self.angle_delta

        elif key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
            self.rotateX[0] -= self.angle_delta

        elif key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
            self.rotateY[0] += self.angle_delta

        elif key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
            self.rotateY[0] -= self.angle_delta

        else:
            return

        glutPostRedisplay()

    def run(self):
        glutMainLoop()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def table_model(radius, number_of_points):
    delta = 2 * pi / (number_of_points - 1)
    points = []

    for i in xrange(number_of_points):
        points.append((radius * cos(i * delta), radius * sin(i * delta), 0.05))
        points.append((radius * cos(i * delta), radius * sin(i * delta), 0))

    return points

def table_leg_model():
    return (
        0, 0,   0, 0.2, 0,
        0, 1,   0, 0.2, 1.0,
        1, 0,   0, 0, 0,
        1, 1,   0, 0, 1.0,
        #0, 0,   0.2, 0, 0,
        #0, 1,   0.2, 0, 1.0,
        #1, 0,   0.2, 0.2, 0,
        #1, 1,   0.2, 0.2, 1.0,
        #0, 0,   0, 0.2, 0,
        #0, 1,   0, 0.2, 1.0,
    )
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Main -------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AppGL("Moe's Tavern", (300, 100), (800, 600)).run()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you very very much. You have been of great help :)